# Shell script for mysql query execution shows error

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell

I'm running the below script

```
mysql -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db << eof
INSERT INTO \`manufacturemap\`
(\`manufacture_id`\ `manufacture_name`\) VALUES (122,IBM)
eof
done
exit
```

but it shows the following **Error**

```
bad substitution: no closing "`" in `manufacture_name'\) VALUES    (122,IBM))
```

I've tried everything I know,Please help, kinda stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `,` and wrong `\`s in ->

```
(\`manufacture_id`\ `manufacture_name`\)
```

Should be -

```
(\`manufacture_id\`, \`manufacture_name\`)
```

No escaping needed -

```
INSERT INTO manufacturemap (manufacture_id, manufacture_name) VALUES (122, 'IBM')
```

Comment: Thank you so much b0s3,You saved my day.More questions coming up ;)